# Can I import database to mysql 5.7 from msyql 8.0.19?

Tags: mysql

I used to use mysql 5.7 for a WordPress site, then I transferred the site to another server using mysql 8.0.19, but I've been problems, so I planning to create another server with mysql 5.7, but since the database was imported to a higher version, I don't know if do a mysqldump and bring the database to the server running 5.7.

1. Does it matter the msyql lower version to import database?
2. There is any special preparation to import database to older version?
3. Can i just mysqldump the database and import it to the 5.7 version?

Comment: see what you have to consider with mysqldump https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: @nbk I only found this option `--compatible=name` but description says that I can only use option is `ansi` so, does it means that the option doesn’t make any difference for what I’m trying to accomplish?
Here’s the description: Produce output that is more compatible with other database systems or with older MySQL servers. The only permitted value for this option is ansi, which has the same meaning as the corresponding option for setting the server SQL mode.

Comment: As i said you can dump it a and see if everything runs in your new server. I woould also try to transfer it ddirectly with workbench, this **can** work. This are only cvomments and not answer, because there is no guaranty that any of will work